# Add image above table - Itext

Tags: java, android, position, itext, itext7

How to add an image over a table with Itext?

**I'm using the version 5.5.10**

**implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'**

**Edit: The image can not be inside the row / column, it must be independent to populate any position on the screen**

I'm trying to add an image over the columns of a table, but the result is this:

[image]

It always lies below the rows of the column.
To add the image I'm doing so:

```
public void addImg (int dwb, float x, float y, float desc) {
    try{
        Bitmap bitmap = dwbToBitmap(context, dwb);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream3);

        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream3.toByteArray());
        stream3.close();
        image.scaleToFit(sizeImgFit, sizeImgFit);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(35.6f + 10f + x, height-y-sizeImg-(height-desc));

        document.add(image);

    }catch (Exception e){
        log("addImg", e);
    }
}
```

I have already tried to change the order, create the first table and then add the images or vise versa, but it does not work.

Does anyone know how to put the images in position Z above all?

I create the table like this:

```
public void createTable(ArrayList<String> header, ArrayList<String[]> clients){
    float height = 569/header.size();
    sizeImg = height;
    sizeImgFit = sizeImg - 2;
    PdfPTable pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(header.size());
    pdfPTable.setWidthPercentage(100);

    PdfPCell pdfPCell;

    int indexC = 0;

    while(indexC < header.size()){
        pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(header.get(indexC++), fHeaderText));
        pdfPCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        pdfPCell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);

    }

    int i = 0;
    for(String[] row : clients){
        int p = 0;
        for(String linha : row){
            pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(linha, fText));
            pdfPCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            pdfPCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            pdfPCell.setFixedHeight(height);

            pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);
            log("linha - coluna", i + " - " + p);
            p++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    //paragraph.add(pdfPTable);

    try {
        document.add(pdfPTable);

    }catch (Exception e){
        log("paragraph", e);
    }
}
```

These methods mentioned above are in a class:

```
public class TemplatePDF {
    private Context context;
    private File pdfFile;
    private Document document;
    public PdfWriter pdfWriter;
    private Paragraph paragraph;
    private Rotate event;
    private Font fTitle = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 20, Font.BOLD);
    private Font fSubTitle = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
    private Font fHeaderText = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 3, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.WHITE);
    private Font fText = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 3);
    private Font fHText = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8);
    private Font fHighText = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 15, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED);
    private float width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
    private float height = PageSize.A4.getHeight();
    public float sizeImg;
    public float sizeImgFit;

    public TemplatePDF(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void openDocument(){
        createFile();

        try{
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
            event = new Rotate();
            document.open();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("erro", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void createFile(){
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "PDF");

        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdirs();
        }

        pdfFile = new File(folder,  key() + ".pdf");
    }

    public void closeDocument(){
        document.close();
    }

    ...

}
```

To create PDF, I do so:

```
        //Creating the object
        TemplatePDF templatePDF = new TemplatePDF(ficha_pre.this);
        templatePDF.openDocument();
        templatePDF.addMetaData("Relatório", "Situs", "Woton Sampaio");
        templatePDF.addTitles("Relatório", "","Data: " + getDate());

        //Creating the table
        ArrayList<String> header = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 55; i++){
            header.add(forString(i));
        }

        ArrayList<pdfItens> itens = arrayItens();
        ArrayList<String[]> files = array();

        templatePDF.createHeaderFicha(itens);
        templatePDF.createTable(header, files);

        //Adding image
        templatePDF.addImg(R.drawable.ic_a, 0, 20, 566);
```

Comment: It isn't clear how you apply the code pieces you posted.

Comment: @mkl I use the code of the part of the table to create the table and the bottom one to add images to the pdf, where you do not understand? So I add more information, I really need help on this question.

Comment: In your code "To create PDF" you call `templatePDF.addImg(R.drawable.ic_a, 20, 566);` but the `addImg` method code you show has four parameters. Thus you either call the wrong method or show the wrong method code.

Comment: @mkl done , I copied wrong when put here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause for this is that an `Image` added to the `Document` is added in a virtual layer underneath that of regular text and tables. Apparently iText developers assumed that text and table elements by default are to be drawn in front of images.

But you can explicitly add the `Image` to a different virtual layer which is in turn above that of text and tables, in `addImg` you merely have to replace

```java
document.add(image);
```

by

```
pdfWriter.getDirectContent().addImage(image);
```

Your `image` in `addImg` has its `AbsolutePosition` set. This actually is necessary for images you want to add to the `DirectContent` because the `DirectContent` has no idea about current insertion positions or page dimensions.

As an aside, there also is a `DirectContentUnder` for stuff that shall go even below the layer of `Images` added via the `Document`.